# Angularjs get total hours using momentjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have 10 records of time. I want to get the total hours using momentjs

Here's my code

**TOTAL HOURS VALUE**

```
00:47:21
00:00:25
00:00:08
00:00:03
00:00:37
16:12:12
04:44:22
01:39:03
00:01:58
16:17:29
```

**MY CONTROLLER**

```
vm.tth = 0;

function getFirst() {

  dataservice.getUserProfile(vm.userId).then(function (data) {
    vm.userlistData2 = data;
    imageservice.getCurrentImage(vm.userlistData2.user_id).then(function (data) {
      vm.photo = data;
    });

    dataservice.getUserAttendance(vm.userlistData2.user_id).then(function (data) {

      vm.attendance = data;

      for( var x=0; x < vm.attendance.length; x++){

        vm.tth += moment.duration(vm.attendance[x].totalHrs);
        console.log(moment(vm.tth).format('HH:mm:ss'));

      }
      return vm.attendance;

    });
  });
}
```

**Output is wrong:**

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are couple of reasons why you are getting that output:

1. You are converting `tth` to *moment*. You should be converting it to **duration**.
2. Your total number of hours are going beyond 24 and hence they are getting mod'ed (hrs % 24). In this case you might want to display number of days along with hours.

Here are the 2 ways you can get the output (check the last couple of lines in console to understand the difference between 2 outputs):

Note: as your question has nothing to do with angularjs, I'm showing plain JS code.

```js
var attendance = [
  '00:47:21',
  '00:00:25',
  '00:00:08',
  '00:00:03',
  '00:00:37',
  '16:12:12',
  '04:44:22',
  '01:39:03',
  '00:01:58',
  '16:17:29'
];

var tth = 0;
for( var x=0; x < attendance.length; x++){

  tth += moment.duration(attendance[x]);
  var d = moment.duration(tth);
  console.log(moment(tth).format('HH:mm:ss') + ' with number of days >> ' + d.days() + ' ' + d.hours() + ':' + d.minutes() + ':' + d.seconds() );
  console.log(moment(tth).format('HH:mm:ss') + ' with hours exceeding 24 ## ' + parseInt(d.asHours()) + ':' + d.minutes() + ':' + d.seconds() );
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.14.1/moment.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Omg! Thank you so much bro finally get the logic on how it work.